# Google plus (photos) sends timeout since the 13th of January

Tags: google-contacts-api

We're having problems with Google Plus API. Since yesterday it sends timeouts for some of our requests (most of them). Does anyone that uses the API has experienced this problem? I have problem contacting someone from Goggle plus to explain the behaviour

Answer (score 1):

This might have something to do with the announcement:
[image]

> The photos space will sunset in early January 2018. Your users can
>   continue to access Google Photos via the drive space by enabling the
>   Google Photos folder in My Drive in the Drive client settings

This is currently posted in Drive API docs.

Check the [How Google Photos works with Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6156103) for more info.